# Angular 2 Routing - get routing parameter - typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

nvm 0.31.0 : npm 3.10.3 : Node.js 6.6.0

From login.component.ts

```
gotoProfile(id:number):void {
    let link = ['/profile'];
    console.log("Routing to /profile/"+id);
    this.router.navigate(link, id);
}
```

Console :

```
Routing to /profile/1
```

From profile.component.ts

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
                private router:Router,
                private profileService:ProfileService) {
    }

ngOnInit():void {
this.route.params
        .subscribe(params => {
            let id = params['id'];
            console.log("id " + id);
            this.profileService.getProfileById(id)
            .subscribe(
                p => this.model = p,
                err => this.handleError(err),
                () => console.log("getting profile complete")
            );
    });
```

From Console :

```
id undefined
```

From app.routing.ts

```
path: 'profile/:id',
component: ProfileComponent
```

If I then type this in the browser : http://localhost:3000/profile/1
Console :

```
id 1
```

So what am I missing here :)

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribe()` method watches for changes in the URL, but in your login component, you are navigating directly with the router.

From the [router docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), the following code snippet shows how to parse the parameters when done that way.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
  let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
   this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
 });
}
```

However, typing in the URL directly will trigger the `subscribe()` method since it is observing the URL directly, and explains why doing it that way works, and you see it in the console log.

Comment: This example is using a Promise, where I am using Observable. I am new to angular and I did go through the Hero tutorial.